# Uninitialized constant error with rspec binstub (bin/rspec), but not with rspec itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this problem intermittently, and would love some ideas to help get it sorted:

Sometimes in my Rails app, when I add a new file (class or module) or I move and rename a class/module I start to see an `Uninitialized constant` error when executing Rspec through the binstub.  However, if I execute `rspec` directly I do not get this error (nor is it present in the development server or on the console).  Just the binstub is suffering this problem.

```
bundle exec bin/rspec # uninitialized constant error
bundle exec rspec     # no errors
```

The only way I'm able to resolve it has been a full restart of my computer.  Not even new terminal sessions can overcome it.  The binstubs load much faster and prefer to rely on them, but restarting my computer when this happens is annoying.

**Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this problem?**

Here is my binstub:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
require 'bundler/setup'
load Gem.bin_path('rspec-core', 'rspec')
```

Comment: Try `spring stop` and see if that fixes it. My guess is spring is running and doesn't see the new file. Running that command should save you from having to restart your computer. There's also a `spring restart` command I believe

Comment: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/519 What the previous two said. I'm also pretty sure I've seen this question asked before like twice haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else finds this useful, @JayDorsey suggestion did the trick:

```
bundle exec spring stop
```

After stopping it, rerunning the the same test using the binstub rectified the issue.